# Getting parse error when trying to set crontab in Laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I got error on cron log like this

> Parse error: parse error in `/Users/mac/downloads/web/tm_mining/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php` on line 235

this is my cron script

```
* * * * * php /Users/mac/downloads/web/tm_mining/artisan schedule:run >> /Users/mac/downloads/web/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

I really have no Idea what is wrong with this. 
Any idea how to fix it ?
I run `php artisan schedule:run` manually, it show message like this

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

when I run my command manually, it is work without any error

Comment: What version of Laravel and what version of PHP? Also, is that the full error message? Usually it tells you what the problem is

Comment: laravel version 5.5.4 . What error message ? I only get error like I wrote above